# Right click context menu

Tags: modeling

I am using the latest 2.8 release. When no object is selected and I right click to add an item such as a mesh the menu doesn't appear.[image: Wrong context menu!]

Comment: You are in the wrong mode, go to edit mode and try right clicking their.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the intended behaviour. Right click menu is for special actions based on the type of object you have selected, not for adding new objects.

To add an object, ensure you are in *Object Mode*, then either

- use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>
- or left click on the *Add" button at the top of the Viewport

  [image]

Comment: But Nicola, why would he expect adding objects with right click, because their was no option in 2.79 too.

Comment: I don't know what OP was used to (maybe a custom keymap?) but he clearly mentions adding new objects in his question

Comment: Oh, this time I didn't read the question carefully, I just saw the heading and...anyways he is done at last.All the best @Umar.

Answer (score 5):

In the preferences, if you choose LMB as select, then context menu is automatically assigned to RMB.

If default RMB as select, then you need to invoke the context menu with 'W'.

Answer (score 0):

You must be in `Edit Mode` to bring context menu.
[image]